# CSS/JavaScript Absolute vs Fixed positioning

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem now that I can't seem to get to the bottom of.

Let's say I have this code:

```
<div id="Father">
   <div style="position:absolute" id="Son">
   Some random content here....
   </div>
</div>
```

Sometimes I need the Son to be full screen so I just apply some top:0; left:0; and width:100%; height:100%; values to it and that's about all because he is not dependent to the Father.
But sometimes I want the Son to stay relative to the Father and not start from the very top of the page so I just apply some position:relative; to the Father and that's it. The Son is "grounded";

My problem is that if I try to use $("#Father").css("position","fixed"); to get the Son out again it doesn't seem to work. It stays relative to the Father no matter what js instructions I give.

P.S. I have refreshed the Son's display (block/none), I don't expect the change to just happen with the Son standing on the screen.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: `$("#Father").css("position",""); ` ?

Comment: OH my God why did I not think of that? So simple :)) Thanks a lot my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child will be positioned absolutely with reference to the first ancestor with a non-`static` position, or to the `<body>` element;

To 'free' an element from it's ancestors' constraints, simply restore it's static position:

```
$('#father').css('position','static');
```

Or, as shown in the comments, you could use an empty string, or invalid value, to cause the browser to discard the rule:

```
$('#father').css('position','');
```